# Elegant way of detecting window.opener cross-origin when accessing it's property

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, window.open, window.opener

I have a parent window on `http://a.com` domain and this window opens with `window.open` a new window on domain `http://b.com`. Now, JS on second (child) window tries to access it's parent property like:

```
 var api = {}

 if(window.opener.parentProp) { // essential to check for this property
   api = window.opener
 } else {
   api = window
 }
```

which generates the following cross-origin error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://b.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

I have figured out the following solution

```
 try {
   if(window.opener.parentProp) { // essential to check for this property
     api = window.opener
   } else {
     api = window
   }
 } catch(e) {
   api = window
 }
```

but how likes `try` and `catch` blocks, right? :D So the question is, are you familiar with more elegant solutions like:

```
if(window.opener.breakingCrossOriginPolicy) // just a simple property name for example purposes
```

?

Comment: I have the same question. Having to use a `catch` adds undesired complexity to the code.